# Run selected test classes with xcodebuild or Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I have several test classes in a test target configured in Xcode. I would like to run some selected tests only.

Say I have the following tests under my test target.

- ClassATests
- ClassBTests
- ClassCTests
- ClassDTests

Say that I want to run tests for ClassA and ClassB but not for ClassC and ClassD.

AFAIK this can't be done in Xcode. I can either run all of the tests or one test class only.

In xcodebuild, in the command line, I can't run those tests either. I have the the `-skip-testing` or `-only-testing` params but I can't make them work with more than one test-identifier.

Is there a way to run those tests in isolation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely possible in XCode itself. Command-click multiple test classes, right-click, and click "Run n test classes"

To achieve the same with Command line, you can use multiple lines of `-only-testing` and `-skip-testing`.

Please refer to the 33:01 minute of this video(Opens only in Safari/WWDC app):
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/409/?time=1982

Comment: You are right! Do you also know how to select several test classes from the command line? In other words, do you know how to specify several test indentifiers to `-only-testing` or `-skip-testing`?

Comment: "You are right!" Could you accept the answer if it works for you? :)

Comment: I'll give it 24 hours. If nobody answers with both the way to do it in Xcode and xcodebuild, I'll set yours as answer :)